# How do I mass convert xlsx files to csv?

Tags: r, excel, vba, csv

I have a folder with around 200 files (incredibly small ones too) that need to be converted to either a delimited txt file or a csv file (which is apparently better). All of them are named 1, 2, 3 etc. The code I found online using VBA doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm on a mac (High Sierra)
Apparently I'm asking more than one question - i don't see how that is as I just need code in one of the programs that works. I'm only posing the programs and different file extensions because I'm looking for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have them all in one folder:

```
library("readxl")


folder = "somewhere"
for(i in list.files(folder,full.names = TRUE)){
    # read  xlsx files
    my_data <- read_excel(i)
    write.csv(x = my_data,file = paste0(i,".csv"))

}
```

You need a library (readxl) to read MS xlxs. With list.files you can easily go through all files.

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again but where are these csv files saved?

Comment: In the same folder as the orginal data.

Comment: library("readxl")
> 
> 
> folder = "sanalyse"
> for(i in list.files(folder,full.names = TRUE)){
+     # read  xlsx files
+     my_data <- read_excel(i)
+     write.csv(x = my_data,file = paste0(i,".csv"))
+     
+ }
Is this correct? (the name of the folder is sanalyse). I run it but the csv files don't show up

Comment: do you get anay errors? you can include a "print(head(my_data))" after the read_excel line to see if the data was read correct.